# Find limit of sequence $n^2 \cos(1/n) - n^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

First of all, this is a homework question, so I would prefer not to have every detail explained.
**Question**: Show that a sequence
$$a_n = n^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - n^2$$
Converges, and find its limit.
I have tried using:

- L'Hôpital's rule,
- The Sandwich Theorem and
- Rewriting the expression where letting $n\to\infty$ would make the limit obvious

Plotting the sequence reveals that it converges towards $-1/2$, but I can't figure out how to show it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{ \cos x-1}{x^2}.$ L'Hospital gives: $f(x) \to -1/2$ as $x \to 0.$ Hence

$$a_n =f(1/n) \to -1/2$$

as $n \to \infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

- Write $\cos\left( \frac1n\right)$ in Taylor expansion form.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
n^2 \cos \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) - n^2  = \frac{{\cos (1/n) - 1}}{{1/n^2 }} =  - 2\frac{{\sin ^2 (1/(2n))}}{{1/n^2 }} =  - \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin (1/(2n))}}{{1/(2n)}}} \right)^2 .
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply Taylor's expansion on the trigonometric component. However, if you are a freshmen in math, you may use the method of equivalent infinitesimal, that is: $1-cos\left(x\right) \sim \frac{1}{2}x^{2}$ at x=0
The result comes out immediately but not rigorously.

Comment: I have not heard of that method, but isn't it just equivalent to Taylor expanding cos(x) to second order?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is only a convenient method for quick calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\cos a-\cos b=-2\sin(a+b)/2 \sin(a-b)/2$$ and obtain
$$a_{n}=\dfrac{\cos(1/n)-1}{1/n^{2}}=-1/2\underbrace{\dfrac{\sin^{2}(1/2n)}{(1/2n)^{2}}}.$$
Since $\dfrac{\sin^{2}(1/2n)}{(1/2n)^{2}}\rightarrow 1$.  Then $a_{n}\rightarrow -1/2$.

Comment: This answer is not so different from my earlier one.

Comment: Yes! But I sear that I was writing this without seeing yours. When I posted it I find it and I let this for more formation. Perhaps, the question was posted by a student!